Reading a resolver in parallel, possible isolator problem?
I have a circuit composed by a driver for a resolver, a digital isolator (150Mbps) and a microcontroller for comunicating in parallel with the driver. It is not working and debugging the circuit I have found that maybe the problem comes from the isolation stage (from 5V to 3.3). I have this is first frame in the 5V side:

But this one in the 3.3V side:

Except for the start up, which it seems (?) to be working properly, having this in the 5V side:

And this in the 3.3V side:

Then, all as logic one.
There are no pull ups in the software.
This is the isolator: MAX14930FAWE+

anything is possible, does that 5V signal look good?
